# Glassfish admin console won't load

Tags: glassfish

I am trying to load the Glassfish V3 admin console but I can't get beyond the log in screen. The credentials I am using are valid but it never makes it to the main admin screen.

Glassfish is installed on a server without an internet connection which I think may be the issue. On my local machine I have no issues at all. I think the admin console is trying to connect to the update center and that is the problem, is there some config that that be changed to stop it looking for updates?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, [this](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11057) issue may be relevant. More info [here](http://markmail.org/message/bkhlicqjqwp7nqby#query:glassfish%20v3%20%22update%20center%22%20cannot%20connect+page:1+mid:7qoa6qvgox7eldrp+state:results).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.